# OpenCV: How to closes edges in a binary image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, contour

I am trying to perform image segmentation on the following image of brain tissue:

[image]

The following is what the segmented result should look like:

[image]

I have the following result which I have obtained after applying thresholding, morphological transformations and contour area filtering (used to remove noise in the image) to the original image:

Result before contour filtering:

[image]

Result after contour filtering:

[image]

However, in my result, some of the black edges got separated/broken apart. Is there any simple method that I can use to close the small gaps between some of the edges.
E.g. is it possible to fill the white spaces between the edges circled in red with black?

[image]

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: you can use erosion to remove the undesired connections

Comment: I don't think erosion would work for this problem. Erosion just makes the boundaries of the foreground object thinner. I am trying to close the gaps in the edges where the edge should be whole but a small gap was introduced after processing the image.

Comment: to remove the gaps as highlighted in the picture, you'll have to first find the regions where these connections exists then you can remove them. The question is how will you find them? you have no clue but the simple solution is to make the white regions thinner and erosion can remove these undesired connection but thickens the black regions (edges in your case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest method would be to attempt to use Morphology. You simply perform a dilation operation followed by an erosion operation.

The following script uses opencv's Morphology function:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

folder = 'C:/Users/Mark/Desktop/'
image = cv2.imread(folder + '6P7Lj.png')
image2 = cv2.bitwise_not(image)
kernel = np.ones((8,8),np.uint8)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(image2, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
closing = cv2.bitwise_not(closing)

cv2.imshow('image', closing)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

This is the results:

[image]

Most of the edges were connected. I'm sure you can further play with the function's kernel to get better results (or even use openCV's separate dilatation and erosion function to get ever more control).

Note: I add to invert the image before performing the operation because it treats white pixels as positive and black as negative, unlike your image. In the end it was inverted again to return to your format.